# Conditionally invoke member function without a temporary var

Tags: scala

I have an expression returning an object, and I want to invoke a method on the resulting object only if a certain boolean condition is true. I want to get the result (whether the object, or the result of invoking the method on the object) in a val.

One way is to use a temporary var, such as in the following example, in which `List(3, 1, 2)` is the (potentially complicated) expression returning an object, `list` is the temporary var, and `.sorted` is the method I want to conditionally invoke:

```
import scala.util.Random

val condition = Random.nextBoolean
val result = {      
  var list = List(3, 1, 2);
  if (condition) list = list.sorted
  list
}
```

What would be the canonical way to do this, perhaps *without* using a temporary var?

Note that

```
if (condition) List(3, 1, 2).sorted else List(3, 1, 2)
```

is not quite satisfactory because `List(3, 1, 2)` may in general be a complicated expression that I don't want to repeat.

Here is one method I found that unfortunately involves giving explicit types (and is longer and more complicated than introducing a temporary var as above):

```
val condition = Random.nextBoolean
val result =
  (
    if (condition)
      {l: List[Int] => l.sorted}
    else
      identity(_: List[Int])
  ).apply(List(3, 1, 2))
```

I suspect there must be a tidier way that I have failed to recognize.

*Update:* A slightly less ugly method that unfortunately still requires explicit type information:

```
val condition = Random.nextBoolean    
val result = {
    l: List[Int] => if (condition) l.sorted else l
  }.apply(List(3, 1, 2))
```

Comment: Is it really worth all the circumlocution to avoid a temporary value? (And you don't need to use a var, just an if / else.)

Comment: @RandallSchulz Not necessarily, of course. But ideally, I would like to avoid both the explicit type information *and* the long-winded solution involving a temporary value! sschaef has shown below that, if the forward pipe operator is available, this is possible.

Comment: It's pretty hard for me to see how _any_ of the alternatives proffered are in any way preferable to the simplest form you showed in your question (the first one).

Comment: sschaef's alternative is preferable in one way at least: it is ~1 line (assuming |> is available) instead of ~3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, the standard library now provides the chaining operation [`pipe`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/util/ChainingOps.html#pipe[B](f:A=%3EB):B) which can be used to convert/pipe a value with a function of interest, and thus avoids an intermediate variable:

```
import scala.util.chaining._

List(3, 1, 2).pipe(list => if (condition) list.sorted else list)
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use the forward pipe operator:

```
implicit class PipedObject[A](value: A) {
  def |>[B](f: A => B): B = f(value)
}

scala> List(3, 1, 2) |> (xs => if (true) xs.sorted else xs)
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Ah! I was wondering if such a "postfix function application" operator existed in Scala. (Any idea if it will be built-in at some point?)

Comment: I don't know but at the moment there are no discussions to include it to the stdlib.