# Conditionally Apply Methods in Scala Elegantly

Tags: scala

Is there a clean way to conditionally apply methods in a long list of methods? I want to do something like this. (whether or not method2 is called, the type of object remains the same so that method3 is still valid)

```
someObject
    .method1()
    if (some condition) {.method2()}
    .method3()
```

This would achieve the same thing as below but I would like to avoid rewriting it completely for each condition, ie

```
if (some condition){
    someObject
        .method1()
        .method2()
        .method3()
}
else {
    someObject
        .method1()
        .method3()
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [`pipe`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52687288/5205022) chaining operator, for example

```
import scala.util.chaining._

object SomeObject {
  def method1 = { println("method1"); this }
  def method2 = { println("method2"); this }
  def method3 = { println("method3"); this }
}

SomeObject
  .method1
  .pipe(someObject => if (condition) someObject.method2 else someObject)
  .method3
```

which if `condition == false` outputs

```
method1
method3
```

otherwise outputs

```
method1
method2
method3
```